# ng-repeat fails on ie-8 despite es5-shim

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint-2010, internet-explorer-8, es5-shim

I have an angular model `page` that has an array `images`. In my template I have this:

```
<div slide="slide" ng-repeat="slide in page.images" active="slide.active">
```

and I have tried to have `es5-shim.js` imported in all orders of precedence that can be. All other browsers render it correctly , except `document mode IE8` (sharepoint 2010 forces this). In that I get:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method<div class="item text-center ng-isolate-scope" active="slide.active" ng-repeat="slide in page.images" slide="slide" ng-transclude ng-class="{&#10;    'active': leaving || (active &amp;&amp; !entering),&#10;    'prev': (next || active) &amp;&amp; direction=='prev',&#10;    'next': (next || active) &amp;&amp; direction=='next',&#10;    'right': direction=='prev',&#10;    'left': direction=='next'&#10;  }" ng-1398662894321="121">
```

The result is that inside that div, an `<img ng-src="{{ slide.url }}"` image gets a bad URL.

If I remove `es5-shim.js` I get also an error about not supported `indexOf` for the same row. Weird thing is, ng-repeat is working elsewhere in the app where I use angular-treeview.

What type error is this, if not indexOf, and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Well, at least `ng-src="{{ slide.url }}"` should be `ng-src="slide.url"`

Comment: Any angular expression inside the div is not processed properly. But you are correct.

In that case the value passed to IE8 is `src="slide.url"`.

Comment: I got this working, by simply reconstructing the ng-repeat. I am happy, but very confused as to what happened/did not happen. It is now `<div slide="slide" ng-repeat="i in page.images" active="i.active"><img ng-src="{{ i.url }}" style="margin:auto;"></div>` and working on all (required) browsers o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using "slide directive" => slide="slide"  and  another slide in ng-repeat="slide in page.images" they are conflicting.

one more suggestion, always prefix your directive.
like ct-slide (ctSlide in javascript)

Comment: This is correct, we figured it out eventually but I forgot to update with answer :)